# Solve the following equation: $7a^2–3b^2=1$, where $a,b$ are two positive integers.

Tags: number-theory

My attempt:

$7a^2–3b^2=1\\
\implies 7a^2=1+3b^2\\
\implies a^2=\frac{1+3b^2}7\\
\implies a=\sqrt{\frac{1+3b^2}7}.$

So for $a$ to be an integer, $3b^2+1$ must be divisible by $7$, and when divided by $7$ the result must be a perfect square. By trying the first few values for $b$, we find that $b=3$ gives us the solution $a=2,b=3$. Is $(2,3)$ the only solution,or are they other ones? Thanks.

Comment: @OscarLanzi, $(1,0)$ is not a solution. I've found three: $(2,3)$ and $(218,333)$, $(23978,36627)$.

Comment: Misread the Q. Comment deleted. Sorry.

Comment: @lhf, kindly can you show how you got the two other solutions?

Comment: Any solution can be obtained from a solution to $u^2-21v^2=7.$ There are infinitely many such solutions, because the solution $(u,v)=(7\cdot 2,3)$ exists.

Comment: I wrote a program

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) will help.

Comment: The [OEIS sequence A041033](https://oeis.org/A041033) has the solutions for "a" as a(6n+2).

Answer (score 3):

$$7a^2-3b^2=1\tag{1}$$

Multiplying both sides by $7$ and let $(x,y)=(7a,b),$ then we get $$x^2-21y^2=7\tag{2}$$

The equation $x^2-21y^2=7$ is called as generalized Pell's equation.

For details, see [Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).

All solutions are given as follows.
Let $(x_{0},y_{0})$ is a solution of $x^2 - 21 y^2 = 7$ and  $(u_{0},v_{0})$ is a fundamental solution of $u^{2}-21v^{2}=1.$

Thus, all of the solutions are $(x_{0}+y_{0}\sqrt{21})(u_{0}+v_{0}\sqrt{21})^n$ with $n=0,1,2,3...$

We know $(x_{0},y_{0})=(14,3)$ and $(u_{0},v_{0})=(55,12)$ by brute force.

We take the integer part as $x$ and the coefficient of $\sqrt{21}$ as $y.$

$(14+3\sqrt{21})(55+12\sqrt{21})^{0} = 14+3\sqrt{21} \implies (x,y)=(14,3) \implies (a,b)=(2,3).$

$(14+3\sqrt{21})(55+12\sqrt{21})^{1} = 1526+333\sqrt{21} \implies (x,y)=(1526,333) \implies (a,b)=(218,333).$

$(14+3\sqrt{21})(55+12\sqrt{21})^{2} = 167846+36627\sqrt{21} \implies (x,y)=(167846,36627) \implies (a,b)=(23978, 36627).$

Similarly, we get $(a,b)=(2637362, 4028637),(290085842, 443113443),(31906805258, 48738450093).$
Thus, we can get the infinitely many solutions of equation $(1).$

Comment: +1 of course. Someone new to the area may appreciate the easy observation that if $(x,y)$ is a solution of $x^2-21y^2=7$ then automatically $7\mid x$ :-)

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen, Thanks.